# Golang function with pointer return

Tags: go, pointers

I just started using Go language. and I found some strange things about pointers in the Go language. Here's an example that confused me. let's say I have a simple module with Golang as follows

[image: directory]

The module I have is the Person module. The Person module is in the person/person.go directory with the following code

[image: Person Module]

then another file to initialize the person module, is in the person/package.go directory with code like the following

[image: Person Module Init]

then I run in main.go like the following

[image: Main Go]

---

## **Problem**

when I change person/package.go to return a pointer like below

[image: Problem]

then main.go becomes an error, and it seems as if it doesn't find the function that I have implemented in Person

[image: Problem]

please help, is there something wrong? Thank You ..

---

sample code is in the link below

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/heuristic-proskuriakova-hqmxv9?file=%2Fmain.go%3A7%2C1-8%2C14

Comment: That is not an error. And why do you need to return pointer to string? A minimal alternative to what you have - https://go.dev/play/p/I7tcUZnr77Q

Comment: And don't post images of code, always post textual equivalents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using pointers in GO you need to remember three aspects namely:

- To get the address of a variable x we prefix the variable with an ampersand `x:=&y`
- To read the contents of a pointer (not the address) we prefix a pointer variable with an asterisk `a:=*b`
- To create a parameter or return value that is a pointer you also prefix the variable type with an asterisk

After looking at your code the following is the reason for the issue you are experiencing.

1. If you want your Gen Method to return a pointer to an interface then you should use the & operator to get the address.

```
func Gen() *Person {
    man := NewPerson()
    return &man
}
```

2. Since you are returning an address to an interface then in your main function you must dereference the pointer to use it, as shown below and remember you are returning two values from the method so you need to assign the return to two variable. In this case since I know that we will not receive an error, I use the discard to ignore the second variable  :

```
func main() {
    man := person.Gen()
    msg, _ := (*man).Greating("Kaido")
    fmt.Println(*msg)
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, apparently my mistake was returning the pointer from the interface